# Проблема в сети Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu

Командой

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Пытаюсь зафиксировать дуплекс 100mb и отключить автоопределение сети. Смотрим:

```
russia@russia-comp:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
 Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                             1000baseT/Full
     Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 3
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: g
    Link detected: yes
```

Казалось бы - все замечательно. НО после перезагрузки компа значение **Advertised auto-negotiation: No** меняется на **Yes** Прописал в `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
pre-up /usr/sbin/ethtool -s $IFACE speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Не помогает. После перезагрузки также становится **Auto-negotiation: Yes**Как можно зафиксировать эти значения чтоб они не менялись?

Comment: А в авто режиме какой линк ?

Comment: Стабильный

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить: а в чем выражена необхоимость жесткой привязки скорости работы?

Comment: если без жесткой привязки то pppoe падает

Comment: странно.. обычно такого не наблюдается

Comment: то-ли я что то непонял, то ли еще...  Вы поднимаете ppoe с компа? А какой интерфейс подключения: что-то не припомню внутренних dsl-модемов...

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать вот так:

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100 duplex full    # разместить над строкой 'exit 0'
```

Взято [отсюда](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100988/how-to-force-network-manager-to-set-auto-negotiation-to-false-off-for-a-particul)